# Inserting items in sub-buckets on S3 using boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

Say I have the following bucket set up on S3

MyBucket/MySubBucket

And, I am planning on serving static media for a website out of MySubBucket (like images users have uploaded, etc.). The way the S3 configurations appear to be currently set up, there is no way to make the top-level bucket "MyBucket" public, so to mimic this you need to make every individual item in that bucket public after it has been inserted.

You can, make a sub-bucket like "MySubBucket" public, but the problem I am currently having is trying to figure out how to call boto to insert a test image into that bucket? Can anyone provide an example?

Thanks

Comment: kinda bumbed out no one could provide an example....is this really not possible?

Answer (score 2):

You actually just need to put the sub bucket name and a `/` before the file name.  The following code snippet will put a file called `'test.jpg'` into MySubBucket. The `k.make_public()` makes that file public, but not necessarily the bucket itself.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

connection = S3Connection(AWSKEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)

bucket = connection.get_bucket('MyBucket')
file = 'test.jpg'
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'MySubBucket/' + file
k.set_contents_from_filename(file)
k.make_public()
```